# QThread Not updating OpenGL VBOs and not rendering anything when calling glBufferData() upon GUI event

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am using QT 4.8, Visual Studio 2008, and OpenGL 3.3

I have two data sets that need to be rendered (statically) in OpenGL. I am using QThread to implement a separate display thread from my QGLWidget. 
If I load both datasets first into main memory, then start the render thread, everything works perfectly, but what I need now is to give the user the flexibility of loading and unloading the second dataset without affecting the first one. 
so I have a button to load the first data set:

```
  void MyView::on_btn_start_clicked()
    {
    // Load first data set from file and start the render thread
    // MyGLObject is a QGLWidget object
    MyGLObject->Data1 = new DataSet1();
    if(MyGLObject->Data1->processCSVFile("filename.csv"))
        {
        MyGLObject->initRenderThread();
        }

    }
```

Here is what iniRenderThread() does:

```
   void MyGLWidget::initRenderThread()
    {
    doneCurrent();
    displayThread.initModelRender();
    displayThread.start();
    }
```

displayThread is a subclass of QThread for which the run() method goes like:

```
void DisplayThread::run()
 {
    MyGLObject->makeCurrent();
    // OPenGL and GLEW initialization here ....
       ...

    // initialize first data set's VAO and VBO
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &Vao_data1);
    glBindVertexArray(Vao_data1);
    glGenBuffers(1, &Vbo_data1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Vbo_data1);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Only generate VAO and VBO for second dataset  (no data there yet)
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &Vao_data2);
    glBindVertexArray(Vao_data2);   
    glGenBuffers(1, &Vbo_data2);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // load shader here
        ...

    while(doRendering)
    {
        if(doResize)
        {
        GLResize(w, h);
        doResize = false;
        }
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            // setup model view matrix and pass it as shader uniform
                      ...
            // Draw first dataset
            glBindVertexArray(Vao_data1);
            glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, NUMVERTS);

            // check if second set is loaded and draw if it is
            if(secondDataLoaded)
               {
                glBindVertexArray(Vao_data2);
                glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, start, (end - start));
                }

        MyGLObject->swapBuffers();

        if(!benchmark)
        {
            Mutex.lock();
            updateFrame = false;
            if(!updateFrame && doRendering && !reloadShader)
            WaitCondition.wait(&Mutex);
                Mutex.unlock();
    }

    frameCounter++;
    }  // end while rendering

 }
```

Now THE IMPORTANT QUESTION IS: where to call glBufferData() for the second dataset??????
I tried calling it in a slot at the DisplyThread class in response to a button click which emits the invoking  signal. 
So a slot in the display thread would go like:

```
     DisplayThread::showSecondSet()
     {
      glBindVertexArray(Vao_data2);
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Vbo_data2);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(dataSet2->vertices), dataSet2->vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
      secondDataLoaded = true;
      }
```

NOTHING APPEARS in the render. I also tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249506/when-to-use-glbufferdata-in-open-gl)  by allocating memory in the slot and then calling glBufferSubData() inside the render loop but still am getting nothing. 
The only way it would render correctly is if I am calling glBufferData() inside the  render loop which is very inefficient. 
Is there anyway I can create the VBO and copy data to it only once when the slot is executed and not inside the render loop?

EDIT: I tried using qDebug() to print something from the showSecondSet() SLOT in displayThread(), it is printing and all other function calls inside the slot are executing normally except for the OpenGL calls. I am guessing it has to do with current GL context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by separating the VBO  calls ( glGufferData() calls) from the draw commands.
I am now keeping 2 boolean variables called "secondDataLoaded" and "doReload" 
Once the second dataset has been loaded into host memory, the application program emits a signal with is connected to the showSecondSet() slot 
now the body of showSecondSet() goes like this:

```
 DisplayThread::showSecondSet()
 {
   secondDataLoaded = true;
   doReload = true;
  }
```

in the rendering loop, I have:

```
    if(secondDataLoaded)
{
    glBindVertexArray(Vao_data2);
    if(doReload)
    {   
                createVBOs();
            doReload = false;
    }
    drawData2();
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Works like a charm :) Thanks everybody for your time and valuable tips.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the VBO update into a slot is the right thing to do. However you also must make sure, that the slot gets executed with the target context being active, which in most scenarios boils down to the slot being executed in the DisplayThread.

In one of the projects at work I had to deal with this problem, and in the end I did it through a bunch of trampoline slots and calls of `QMetaObject::invoke` calls. For example in the production code there is the following:

```
class … {
public slots:
    void doFoobar(
            unsigned int a,
            unsigned int b ) {
                    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "_priv_loslot_doFoobar",
                    Qt::QueuedConnection,
                    Q_ARG(unsigned int, a),
                    Q_ARG(unsigned int, b) );
            }
private slots:
    void _priv_loslot_doFoobar(
            unsigned int a,
            unsigned int b );
};
```

Yes it is crude, yes it is a workaround, but it gets the job done. Note that did this then to do something very similar like you're trying: Live update of data in a OpenGL buffer object, performed by a worker thread with its own OpenGL context.

> NOTHING APPEARS in the render

Updating just the VBO doesn't suffice. OpenGL is not a scene graph and the VBO by itself is just a hunk of memory without form. You need to invoke a full redraw to make the changes visible.

Comment: display thread is stuck in the while in run so the slot will never be executed

Comment: @ratchetfreak: In the thread's `run` method call `exec()` so that signals are processed. Use `startTimer(0)` to enable idle loop processing through a timer event and move the stuff within the loop (without the `while`) into a overwriten `timerEvent` member.

Comment: that wouldn't work because startTimer would run the timerEvent in the main thread, the `DisplayThread` object's thread is still the main thread

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Well, you can use `invokeMethod` from `timerEvent` to signal a slot which will then be executed in the thread.

Comment: you still need an object in that thread for the slot to be activated in the thread

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Just use the thread object itself. Call `this->moveToThread(this);` in the `DisplayThread` constructor.

Comment: that is not how you should be using qthreads, my solution with a separate object moved to the other thread is better

Comment: @ratchetfreak: I know that this is quite dirty, but at the time when I was confronted with a problem very much like yours, this was the solution that delivered the best results (at that time). YMMV

Comment: The slot itself is being executed in my code. Once the data is loaded, the slot is executed, I can print data items from it using qDebug() and I know the data is loaded correctly. However, it is the glBindBuffer()  and glBufferData() calls that are not executed. I am not sure what "trampoline slots" would do in this case but I'd like to give it a try. I agree with what you said about having to do a complete redraw on e new data have arrived. The question is: how? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MaYa: That OpenGL calls are not carried out may be to the (trivial) reason, that a OpenGL context can be "current" in only one thread at a time. The easiest way around this is to create a second OpenGL context, that shares textures, PBOs, VBOs. Unfortunately Qt-4.8 makes is a bit hard to do this cleanly and portably.

Comment: @MaYa: When I faced the problem I'd create a "helper" QGLWidget in the thread constructor sharing context data with the main widget; don't call `show` so that it stays invisible. in the thread constructor call `QGLWidget::doneCurrent` to detach that widgets GL context from the thread and in the thread `run` call call `QGLWidget::makeCurrent`.

Comment: @MaYa: If you feel adventurous you may make direct use of the underlaying system APIs (WGL/GLX/etc.) to create a shared context without the need for an extra window or widget.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a new QObject and moving moving the body of the while to a slot of that object and using a QTimer to let it repeat:

```
void DisplayHandler::started()//slot connected to the running's QThread's started
{
    MyGLObject->makeCurrent();
    // OPenGL and GLEW initialization here ....
       ...

    // initialize first data set's VAO and VBO
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &Vao_data1);
    glBindVertexArray(Vao_data1);
    glGenBuffers(1, &Vbo_data1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Vbo_data1);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Only generate VAO and VBO for second dataset  (no data there yet)
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &Vao_data2);
    glBindVertexArray(Vao_data2);   
    glGenBuffers(1, &Vbo_data2);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // load shader here
        ...

}

void DisplayHandler::draw()//slot called when update needs to happen
{

    MyGLObject->makeCurrent();
    if(doResize)
    {
    GLResize(w, h);
    doResize = false;
    }
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // setup model view matrix and pass it as shader uniform
                  ...
        // Draw first dataset
        glBindVertexArray(Vao_data1);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, NUMVERTS);

        // check if second set is loaded and draw if it is
        if(secondDataLoaded)
           {
            glBindVertexArray(Vao_data2);
            glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, start, (end - start));
            }

    MyGLObject->swapBuffers();

    MyGLObject->doneCurrent();
    frameCounter++;

}

void DisplayHandler::showSecondSet()
{
      MyGLObject->makeCurrent();
      glBindVertexArray(Vao_data2);
      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Vbo_data2);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(dataSet2->vertices), dataSet2->vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
      secondDataLoaded = true;
      MyGLObject->doneCurrent();
}
```

then to start the thread:

```
void MyGLWidget::initRenderThread()
{
    doneCurrent();
    QThread* thr = new QThread(this);
    connect(thr, &QThread::started, &displayThread, &DisplayHandler::started);
    connect(this, &QObject::destroyed, thr, &QThread::quit);

    displayThread.moveToThread(thr);
    displayThread.initModelRender();
    thr.start();
}
```

Comment: nothing I moved the part before the while into started and the body of the while into draw, remember DisplayHandler just inherits from QObject and gets moved to the other thread after creation

Comment: I think I had gotten that wrong cuz I thought that displayThread is the same object I had before. I get from your comment now that it is instanced from the DisplayHandler class.. is that correct?

Comment: To clarify my question: I initially kept the QThread subclass (which I call DisplayThread) and created a new DisplayHandler class which sub-classes QObject. I then found myself moving everything to the handler object that is why I was confused about what still goes in the run() of DisplayThread. I will now edit DisplayThread to the above description of DisplayHandler.

Comment: It's not working. The second data set is not appearing no matter how many times the draw() slot is called. I am getting the same behavior as before (except this time there is no event loop so my mouse interactions are gone, I tried creating a QEventLoop and calling exec() in started() but I am not sure what I am doing here). Now I am sure this problem has to do with the context not thread execution. in my initial code, I edited my question to mention the fact that the showSecondSet() slot is executing except for OpenGL calls. it has to be the OpenGL context. Right?